# sticky nav - JS Waypoints issue with custom sticky nav on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a demo of a custom sticky nav.

Demo: http://evanzio.github.io/custom-sticky-header-nav/

Repo: https://github.com/evanzio/custom-sticky-header-nav

Functional Spec:

Header should stick to bottom of client window when landing on page.
When scrolling down, the header should remain fixed.
Once first image has become fully visible, header should stop sticking to the bottom and continue moving with the scroll.
Once the header hits the top of client viewport it will then stick to the top.

This all works fine, until a window resize. Once the page is resized from large to small, the waypoints seem to mess up and the header sticks and unsticks at random points.

Steps to replicate issue.

1. Load page in large
2. scroll to bottom of the page
3. resize browser width to small
4. start scrolling back up and you will see it jump around and leave a white space where the header should be.

I believe on resize the waypoints should refresh automatically, so not sure why this is breaking? Anyone have any ideas?

Or any other ways to achieve the functional spec?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after some playing around, I realised it was because I had a fixed position on a waypoint element. Which is a NO NO!